# Prisoner's Dilemma in Python

Tags: python

At school in my CSE class, I'm working on an optional project, which is code a version of Prisoner's Dilemma into Python. This is my code. When i run it, it starts to work, then once it hits the if statements, it returns with the error, `'TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`. How do I fix this?

```
import random
def ipd_start():
    print("Welcome to Prisoner's Dilemma. \n If you don't know what Game Theory is, you're in the wrong place. \n \n Enter Collude to collude, or Betray to betray.")
    round_one()

def round_one():
    answer=(input("You and a buddy got caught commiting a crime. Do you keep quiet, or rat on your best friend? \n "))
    a = ["Collude", "Betray"]
    G = random.choice(a)
    print("You chose " + answer + ", and your partner chose " + G + ". ")
    if all(G == "Collude" and answer==("Collude")):
        both_free()
    if all(G == 'Collude' and answer==('Betray')):
        you_free()
    if all(G == 'Betray' and answer=='Betray'):
        both_jail
    if all(G == 'Betray' and answer=='Collude'):
        you_jail
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the use of `all`, in this case you can remove it.

Comment: You can also leave out the extra brackets around `input` and the string constants `'Betray'` and `"Collude"`.

Answer (score 3):

`all(iterable)` expects an iterable argument. [PyDocs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all). However you gave it a Boolean. Let's break down that first `if` statement.

```
if all(G == "Collude" and answer==("Collude")):
```

So if `G == "Collude"` will return a Boolean as well as `answer == ("Collude")`. You `AND` them together which produces another Boolean. So in the end you're passing a Boolean and not the required iterable to all.

Make your `if` statement look more like this:

```
if G == "Collude" and answer==("Collude"):
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements use the all() function. This takes an iterable, not a boolean statement. That is what the Error is about.

To fix, try removing the all() function, and keep it a complete boolean statement;

```
if G == 'Betray' and answer == 'Collude':
    you_jail()
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `all` expects a sequence of booleans and returns whether all of them are `True`. You passed it a single boolean expression, which produces the error mentioned above.

I think you can just leave away the call of `all`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `all(G == "..." and answer == "...")`. Choose either `G == "..." and answer == "..."` or `all(G == "...", answer == "...")`, you can't do both. The exact error you get is because the `and` produces a boolean, and `all` needs a list or something it can iterate/loop over.